# Where are the saves for Pop Cap games located?

Tags: popcap

I want to copy my saves from one computer to another, and I'm not sure where they are located. I'm interested in the save files for the games from Pop Cap (Bejeweled Twist, Peggle, Bookworm, for example).

Where are they saved? (I'm assuming that they're all in the same place, since they're from the same publisher and developers)

*Note: I'm moving the saves from a computer running Windows XP to one with Windows 7, so I'm interested in both locations.*

Comment: the location differs a bit in windows-xp and windows7 .. so, what do you run?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The location of the save games depends on your OS

For Windows XP they're in `C:\Program Files\PopCap Games\[game]\Users`.
Windows Vista and 7 they're in `C:\ProgramData\PopCap Games\[game]\userdata`.
If using Steam (Vista onwards) they're in `C:\ProgramData\Steam\[game]`'.

You might need to turn on hidden folders to see them.

For Mac OS X the folder is `[username]/Library/Application Support/PopCap/[game]`.

Just copy that whole folder over and save it on the other computer.